# Where can a list of GitHub achievements be found?

Tags: github

I want to make my GitHub look awesome.
Are there some achievements that I can quickly get on GitHub?

I found this excellent [reference](https://github.com/Schweinepriester/github-profile-achievements) but it's not enough.
What are all the achievements in GitHub and what is the criteria to achieve them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GitHub's blog post where they announced this feature, [Introducing Achievements: recognizing the many stages of a developer’s coding journey](https://github.blog/2022-06-09-introducing-achievements-recognizing-the-many-stages-of-a-developers-coding-journey/), they mention they aren't providing the full list of achievements.

> **What achievements are there?**
>
> Great question, we’ll never tell
>
> There’s a bit of whimsy, surprise, and delight that we hope you’ll
> feel upon discovering achievements on your own profile, as well as on
> your fellow contributors’ and maintainers’ profiles. You will be able
> to infer the criteria to unlock certain achievements by viewing an
> achievement you’ve earned, or by viewing someone else’s achievements.

So unfortunately, we won't know for sure what all the achievements are, but awesome repos like the one you linked, [Schweinepriester/github-profile-achievements](https://github.com/Schweinepriester/github-profile-achievements), seems like the best way to work towards them. Then as the community find more, I'd imagine repos like this will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Github Achievements** are badges of honor displayed on your Github Profile that represent your activities, contributions, and milestones within the Github community. They serve as validations of your skills, dedication, and involvement in various projects and collaborations. These achievements are automatically unlocked once certain criteria have been fulfilled.

[image]

**How to unlock all github achievements?**

I got all github achievements from [Github Achievements - The Ultimate guide](https://githubachievements.com/)